# squid basic_ldap_auth strip nt domain from usernames

Tags: linux, authentication, active-directory, ldap, squid

I need to migrate from a windows based proxy to a linux one.
In the old server Squid uses mswin_auth.exe to authenticate user against an Active Directory domain. For this reason my users now enter ntdomain\username in the browser popup for proxy authentication.

In the linux Centos server Squid will use basic_ldap_auth, in this case the ntdomain must not be entered by the user. It will be very annoying for  my users to change the old habit. Is there a way to automatically remove the ntdomain from the entered username?

In squid.conf I have

```
    auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth -R -b "dc=ntdomain,dc=parentd,dc=it" -D "CN=squid,OU=Squid,OU=Sede,DC=ntdomain,DC=parentd,DC=it" -W /etc/squid/squid.adpwd -f sAMAccountName=%s -h vfdc1.ntdomain.parentd.it
        ...
    external_acl_type ldap_group %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_ldap_group_acl -R -b "dc=ntdomain,dc=parentd,dc=it" -D "CN=squid,OU=Squid,OU=Sede,DC=ntdomain,DC=parentd,DC=it" -W /etc/squid/squid.adpwd -f "(&(objectclass=person) (sAMAccountname=%u)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=%g,OU=Squid,OU=Sede,DC=ntdomain,DC=parentd,DC=it))" -h vfdc1.ntdomain.parentd.it -S
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use -K option in your request (it Strip Kerberos realm from usernames):

```
external_acl_type ldap_group %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_ldap_group_acl -R -K -b "dc=ntdomain,dc=parentd,dc=it" -D "CN=squid,OU=Squid,OU=Sede,DC=ntdomain,DC=parentd,DC=it" -W /etc/squid/squid.adpwd -f "(&(objectclass=person) (sAMAccountname=%u)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=%g,OU=Squid,OU=Sede,DC=ntdomain,DC=parentd,DC=it))" -h vfdc1.ntdomain.parentd.it
```

and all be fine.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution: I created to small bash script based on sed  to strip the domain and used it squid.conf as in

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/bin/squid_auth
```

where the file /usr/local/bin/squid_auth is

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sed -u "s/^ve[\\]//i"|/usr/bin/sed -u "s/^ve%5c//i"|/usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth  -R -b "dc=ve,dc=dipvvf,dc=it" -D "CN=squid,OU=Squid,OU=Sede,DC=ve,DC=dipvvf,DC=it" -W /etc/squid/squid.adpwd -f sAMAccountName=%s -h vfdc1.ve.dipvvf.it
```

The domain name is **ve**